# which version of itext7 is compatible with .net 6.0

Tags: .net-core, itext7

I have installed itext7 version 7.2.3 in .net6.0 but I was getting the following error, if you have any solution regarding that please help.

Thank you

Errors :

```
  The type or namespace name 'PdfPTable' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'PdfPCell' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'FontFactory' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'DocumentException' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'BaseFont' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'Phrase' could not be found
  The type or namespace name 'BaseColor' could not be found
```

[you will see errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIA9G.png)

Comment: Your code is not iText 7. Please include your code and error messages into your question

Comment: The errors you copied into your question are not iText 7 classes. Apparently you have installed iText 7 but your source is for iText 5 or earlier.